# Python - generate random figures in ratio

Tags: python, list

> I need a script which returns a list of random figures from
> range(-100;+100) in ratio of positive/negative figures = 2/1. Current
> wording returns voluntary ratio

```
import numpy as np

x=[]
for y in range(10):
    y=np.random.randint(-100,100)
    x.append(y)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

neg = np.random.randint(-100, -1, 10)
poz = np.random.randint(0, 100, 20)

res = np.concatenate((neg, poz), axis=0)
print(res)
np.random.shuffle(res)#If you need to mix
print(res)
```

As an option.

Comment: very good option, thanks. But res1 is 'None Type' object. Are there any options to convert it to "List" type?

Comment: Check the box to vote)

Comment: Corrected the message. res 1 is not needed.